# Inventory app error ORA-00936 Missing Expression

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, oracle

I'm having some issues with a couple of different areas that I have narrowed down to specific SQL inserts but I can't figure out where the problem is within each area.  Here is the first one and this one is giving me a missing expression error when I step through the application.  This is just an inventory app.

```
        STSQL = "Select mpcs.SI_KEY.nextval from mpcs.one_row"
        rsMPCS = MPCS_SELECT_SQL(UCase(STSQL), rsMPCS)
        rsMPCS.Read()
        varSi = rsMPCS("nextval")
        rsMPCS.Close()
        STSQL = "insert into mpcs.shop_inventory"
        STSQL = STSQL & " ("
        STSQL = STSQL & "SI_KEY,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "INV_TYPE,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "MTI_PART_NO,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "BUILD_NO,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "SERIAL_NO,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "HOME_LOCATION,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "HOME_LOCATION_SUB,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "DESCRIPTION,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "CATEGORY,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "QUANTITY,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "MIN_QTY,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "CONSUMABLE,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "CUST_PART_NO,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "UOM,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "WEIGHT,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "SCRAP_FLAG,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "NEXT_CAL,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "INTERVAL,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "SIZE_1,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "SIZE_2,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "SIZE_3"
        STSQL = STSQL & ") values ("

        STSQL = STSQL & varSi & "," 'SI_KEY
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & strINV_TYPE_selected & "'," 'INV_TYPE

        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & lblMTI.Text & "'" & "," 'MTI_PART_NO
        STSQL = STSQL & cboBuildNumber.Text & "," 'BUILD_NO
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & txtSerialNumber.Text & "'," 'SERIAL_NO
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & cboLocation.Text & "'," 'HOME_LOCATION
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & cboLocationSub.Text & "'," 'HOME_LOCATION_SUB
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & txtDescription.Text & "'," 'DESCRIPTION
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & ListBox1.SelectedValue & "'," 'CATEGORY
        If chkConsumable.Checked Then
            STSQL = STSQL & txtQuan.Text & "," 'QUANTITY
            STSQL = STSQL & txtMin.Text & "," 'MIN_QTY
            STSQL = STSQL & "1," 'CONSUMABLE
        Else
            STSQL = STSQL & "1," 'QUANTITY
            STSQL = STSQL & "0," 'MIN_QTY
            STSQL = STSQL & "0," 'CONSUMABLE
        End If

        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & txtCustomerPartNumber.Text & "'," 'CUST_PART_NO
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & txtUOM.Text & "'," 'UOM
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & txtWeight.Text & "'," 'WEIGHT
        If chkScarp.Checked Then
            STSQL = STSQL & "1," 'SCRAP_FLAG
        Else
            STSQL = STSQL & "0," 'SCRAP_FLAG
        End If
        Dim ctoDate As Date = lblNextCal.Text
        STSQL = STSQL & "to_date('" & Format(ctoDate, "dd-MMMM-yyyy") & "','DD-MON-YYYY'),"

        STSQL = STSQL & txtCalInvdays.Text & ","
        STSQL = STSQL & cboSizeOD.Text & ","
        STSQL = STSQL & cboSizeID.Text & ","
        STSQL = STSQL & cboSizeLength.Text
        STSQL = STSQL & ")"
        MPCS_UPDATE_SQL(UCase(STSQL))
```

I'm not sure what the missing expression is in the following:

```
insert into mpcs.shop_inventory (SI_KEY,INV_TYPE,MTI_PART_NO,BUILD_NO,SERIAL_NO,HOME_LOCATION,HOME_LOCATION_SUB,DESCRIPTION,CATEGORY,QUANTITY,MIN_QTY,CONSUMABLE,CUST_PART_NO,UOM,WEIGHT,SCRAP_FLAG,NEXT_CAL,INTERVAL,SIZE_1,SIZE_2,SIZE_3) values (28990,'TEST','01400010002',0,'0','DEPT-850','DEPT-850','Test','001',1,0,0,'','BOTTLES','3',0,to_date('27-June-2008','DD-MON-YYYY'),0,,,)
```

Comment: Please stop for a while and search how to use a parameterized query. You will need a bit of time but the gain at the end will be more than rewarding

Comment: What does that SQL statement you are constructing look like when you write it out?

Comment: This is madness and it is easy to attack using SQL Injection. Search for binding parameters/prepared statement.

Comment: I was afraid it was whack.  I didn't write this, I inherited it and unfortunately I'm in a position where I don't have time to rewrite things but instead "make it work".  I'm everyone has been in that position and hopefully I can get more time.